# Implementing back, home and recent apps button for android

Tags: android

I'm making a custom my own navigation bar which will have back, home and recent toggle apps. I'm not using the android provided buttons. I just want to make my own. I made the code for home and recent apps button but could not find code for back button. Anyone knows how to do it. Please, its been a week and I'm tired searching about it and nothing seems to work at all. I know its too much to ask but if you have the code to implement the back button for custom navigation bar, please post it. I desperately need help.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you want to use the default navigation bar?

Comment: @Nicklas Because I want to build my own buttons which apart from these features, will have many other functions. Do you know how to do it? Thanks